# upload file in document library based on file name

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I will have document library with field state, country and few folders like 101, 102 etc

I have file name like 102_A_B.txt
When user try to upload the file it should go automatically to folder 102 and state should be filled A and country as B (based on file name).

How to do this using jquery or script.
I am using o365

Answer (score 2):

What you want here could be implemented by using content organizer rules...

They allow you to check fields and then move the content based on the results of the check.

Have a look here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Content-Organizer-rules-to-route-documents-74DFE36D-E3D6-40B7-9A5C-BEEA0C84DEED

and here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.recordsmanagement.recordsrepository.ecmdocumentrouterrule.aspx

Comment: there will b bulk file upload

Comment: Bulk is still one file after another. The Drop of DocLib will be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

After move files to specific folders via content organizer rules. Workflow can set column values automatically.

In the workflow, you can split file names via custom action, and set "State" and "Country" field using split strings.